# "possibly uninitialized variable" when it is initialized inside `match`

Tags: rust, initialization

This code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8acff2060eaf8ef647278d1f95843aa4)):

```rust
fn main() {
    let fruits = "banana";
    let num = 20;
    let result: i32;

    match fruits {
        "banana" => {
            if num > 100 {
                result = num * 3;
            } else if num > 30 {
                result = num * 4;
            } else {
                result = num * 5;
            }
        }
        "apple" => {
            if num > 100 {
                result = num * 16;
            } else if num > 30 {
                result = num * 18;
            } else {
                result = num * 20;
            }
        }

        _ => println!("wrong fruits option"),
    }
    // if num > 100 { result = num * 3; }
    // else if num > 30 { result = num * 4; }
    // else { result = num * 5;}
    println!("{}", result)
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `result`
  --> src/main.rs:31:20
   |
31 |     println!("{}", result)
   |                    ^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `result`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

As you can see `result` is initialized in match, so why is compiler giving me an error?

After changing the line

```rust
let result : i32;
```

to ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2bf8a5f5941f1a215e78d6eeee44f52f))

```
let mut result = 0;
```

The code is compiling and working fine.

This is also working ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e1088dd4c72ffe59d7c5c330bbb0928)):

```rust
fn main() {
    // let fruits = "banana";
    let num = 20;
    let result: i32;

    // match fruits {
    //     "banana" => {
    //         if num > 100 {
    //             result = num * 3;
    //         } else if num > 30 {
    //             result = num * 4;
    //         } else {
    //             result = num * 5;
    //         }
    //     }
    //     "apple" => {
    //         if num > 100 {
    //             result = num * 16;
    //         } else if num > 30 {
    //             result = num * 18;
    //         } else {
    //             result = num * 20;
    //         }
    //     }

    //     _ => println!("wrong fruits option"),
    // }
    if num > 100 {
        result = num * 3;
    } else if num > 30 {
        result = num * 4;
    } else {
        result = num * 5;
    }
    println!("{}", result)
}
```

Comment: ignore any grammatical and spelling mistakes as i am dyslexic, sorry

Comment: Compiler says use of possibly-uninitialized `result`. You don't initialize result in case of '_'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `result` may be uninitialized is that the `_` case does not initialize `result`.

However, I don't think your *intention* is to initialize `result` in that case. The real error here is probably that you probably intended the `_` case to be an error case that stops the execution. However, you didn't tell it to stop the execution.

There is multiple ways to solve that:

- Add a `return` or `exit` statement in the `_` case
- Replace the `println` with a `panic`
- Introduce proper error handling by adding a `Result` return value to main and then return an error.

For the least amount of effort I decided to go with a `panic`. Just be aware that in production, panics should be the very last solution. Proper error handling with `Result` and `Error` is always preferred.

So here's my minimal modification to make it work:

```rust
fn main() {
    let fruits = "banana";
    let num = 20;
    let result: i32;

    match fruits {
        "banana" => {
            if num > 100 {
                result = num * 3;
            } else if num > 30 {
                result = num * 4;
            } else {
                result = num * 5;
            }
        }
        "apple" => {
            if num > 100 {
                result = num * 16;
            } else if num > 30 {
                result = num * 18;
            } else {
                result = num * 20;
            }
        }

        _ => panic!("wrong fruits option"),
    }
    // if num > 100 { result = num * 3; }
    // else if num > 30 { result = num * 4; }
    // else { result = num * 5;}
    println!("{}", result)
}
```